# How to delete ScheduleInstance from sheet?

Tags: revit-api

As we know we have method ViewSheet.DeleteViewPort() method to remove ViewPort from sheet, but i can not find method to remove ScheduleInstance from Sheet, I also try doc.Delete(elementId) method, but it’s not work . So how i can delete it from sheet ???

Answer (score 2):

`Document.Delete` works for me:

```
UIDocument uiDoc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument;
Document doc = uiDoc.Document;
using (var tr = new Transaction(doc, "Delete"))
{
  if (tr.Start() == TransactionStatus.Started)
  {
    ICollection<ElementId> ids = uiDoc.Selection.GetElementIds();
    doc.Delete(ids);
    tr.Commit();
  }
  else
  {
    throw new UserException("Transaction can not be started.");
  }
}
```

Are you calling `Commit` on your transaction?

Also it's `ScheduleSheetInstance`, not `ScheduleInstance`.